# I'm missing Page Layout Button On SharePoint 2010 Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, edit, page-layout

When I want to edit page in Browser I can't see "Page Layout" Button in top ribbon of SharePoint 2010!
I searched for three hours about this problem but I didn't found any solution. Please tell me how to resolve this or check some settings.
(I activate Publishing in features and SP designer show to me Page Layout link in left navigation).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the feature is not enabled that allows the layouts.

To fix the issue go to **Site Actions** -> **Site Settings** in the upper left corner.

Under **"Site Collection Administration"** click on **"Site Collection Features"**.

Look for *"SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"* and activate it. It might take a moment to load.

Next return to **"Site Settings"** and click on **"Manage Site Features"**

Look for *"SharePoint Server Publishing"* and activate it. It might take a moment to load.

**Note:**

If you don't have the Site Collection Administration section of your settings you can try skipping to the next part. However if the site collection does not have this enabled then you will get an error when trying to activate it on the site. You will need to get into the site collection's options.

After making a new site you can go into Site Features and again enable SharePoint Server Publishing. This worked fine on a blank webpage so a publishing page/site is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a publishing page to manipulate a page layout. This page is not a publishing page, it is a wiki page.

Go to **site actions**-->**More options**-->**Publishing Page**. You will be able to see the option then.

And then,when you try to edit the publishing page,you will see the pagelayout button right there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Site Features and deactivate the wiki home page feature

Answer (score 0):

The default page type that is created in a site in SharePoint 2010 is not part of the publishing feature.  You are trying to create a page based on a non-publishing content type even after enabling the publishing feature.  You are most likely trying to add a page to the "Site Pages" library.  This is why the button is not there.

You need to go to Site Actions-> Site Settings-> Page layouts and site templates and set the default template to a publishing page.  And/or you need to add a page to the "Pages" library that was created by the publishing feature as that will support different page layouts.

Comment: i test it but not work."Pages" Library is document Library and i can't change and edit page in browsers... my problem has not resolved yet :( thanks for your reply dear.